# Hibernate not returning newly inserted record

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am developing one web application using following frameworks :

```
Spring 4.2.4.RELEASE
Hibernate 4.3.6.Final
MySQL Connector 5.1.31
Jackson 2.6.5
MySQL 5.7
```

I am creating a new record on the basis of user inputs captured via JSP.

Below is the code for inserting a new record using hibernate

```
public Record addRecord(Record record) {
    logger.info("Persisting new record : " + record);
    Record createdRecord = null;
    SessionFactory hibSessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session hibSession = hibSessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction hibTransaction = hibSession.beginTransaction();
    int record ID = hibSession.save(record);
    hibTransaction.commit();
    hibSession.flush();
    hibSession.close();
    logger.info("Persisted new record : " + createdRecord);
    createdRecord = getRecordById(recordID);
    logger.info("Created record : " + createdRecord);
    return createdRecord;
}
```

I am using page redirect on the same page after inserting new after calling get all records. But problem I am facing after redirect it is not showing all records except the latest record. But when I do a page refresh it shows me all records including the latest record.

Below is the controller code :-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "records/addRecord", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void addRecord(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String recordId = request.getParameter("record_id");
    String recordName = request.getParameter("record_name");
    String recordAddress = request.getParameter("record_address");
    String recordCity = request.getParameter("record_city");
    String recordState = request.getParameter("record_state");
    int recordZip = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("record_zip"));
    Record newRecord = new Record();
    newRecord.setRecordID(Integer.parseInt(recordId));
    newRecord.setRecordName(recordName);
    newRecord.setRecordAddress(recordAddress);
    newRecord.setRecordCity(recordCity);
    newRecord.setRecordState(recordState);
    newRecord.setRecordZIP(recordZip);
    logger.info("Received request to add record : " + newRecord);
    Record addedRecord = recordService.addRecord(newRecord);
    logger.info("Request for adding record completed, added record - " + addedrecord);
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    response.sendRedirect("/RecordApp/records.jsp");
}
```

NOTE : There is no caching used in the hibernate configuration file.

Comment: I think its not hibernate issue, can you show us the controller code ?

Comment: included in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the code that is used for displaying the records.

Answer (score 0):

Record before you apply the `save` method is a transient object, once you apply

```
hibSession.save(record);
```

it save it in the database, but this save `method` returns the `Serializable` identifier for that record, what you could do is use identifier and get it from the database, do this `createdRecord = record;` is basically pass the same object to the return value

```
Integer id = hibSession.save(record);
Record createdRecord = hibSession.get(Record.class,id);
return createdRecord
```

Comment: You mean to say, the created object will not contain object of latest created record.

Comment: What I try to said is that the managed entity (persistent data) is not returned by the method itself.

Comment: Okay, but I am using the same approach for other pages also, there I am getting last added record, consistently. On some pages I am not getting it.

Comment: I have modified my code to fetch newly created record in another session (modified the code snippet). Still I am not getting newly inserted record (I can see the record in DB). Same is happening with updated records. Can it be issue with network/thread latency?